# ExtentReport using gradle

Tags: extentreports

In my project I using gradle. following are my dependencies for cucumber and extent report

```
testCompile group: 'com.vimalselvam', name: 'cucumber-extentsreport', version: '3.1.1'
testCompile group: 'com.aventstack', name: 'extentreports', version: '4.0.9'
testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.2.0'
testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.2.0'
compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12
```

Also, i have created extent-config.xml file  in resources folder. In my Testrunner class i have following code

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)@CucumberOptions(features = "featurefiles", plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports","com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/report.html" },glue = {"StepDefinition","FunctionsLibrary/DataTableConfigurer.java"},tags = "@Runthistest")

public class TestRunner {
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
ExtentProperties extentProperties = ExtentProperties.INSTANCE;
extentProperties.setReportPath("target/myreport.html");
}
@AfterClass
  public static void report(){
Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("src/test/resources/extent-config.xml"));

 }
}
```

I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter
```

any help here is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

With Cucumber version 4, use one of the official adapters:

```
testCompile group: 'com.aventstack', name: 'extentreports-cucumber4-adapter', version: '1.0.6'
testCompile group: 'com.aventstack', name: 'extentreports', version: '4.0.9'
testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.2.0'
testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.2.0'
compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12
```

https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter

Comment: Can you please copy the complete build.gradle file here.